# Marquee Effect on V7 ActionBar Items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the v7 support actionbar and got 3 items there: one is a text, the other two are icons.
Depending on the choosen options the text changes, which is no problem, but if the text is to long, both icon items can't be seen anymore.
So I want to add a marquee effect to the text item, to ensure that the both items with icons are allways visable . How can I achive that?

Here is my update code for the actionbar:

```
private void updateActionBar() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            MenuItem addFavoriteItem=menu.getItem(FAVORITE_MENU_ITEM); //R.id.action_fav dosn't work here :/
            MenuItem nameItem=menu.getItem(ALBUMNAME_MENU_ITEM);

            int id=R.drawable.ic_add_favorite;
            if(gridview.getAdapter() instanceof CategoryAdapter)
            {
            nameItem.setTitle("");
            nameItem.setTitleCondensed("");
                if(gridview.getAdapter().getClass() == CategoryAdapter.FavoriteAdapter.class)
                {
                id=R.drawable.ic_favorite;
                }
            } else if(gridview.getAdapter() instanceof AlbumAdapter)
            {
                Album a=((AlbumAdapter)gridview.getAdapter()).getAlbum();
                if(isFavorite(a))id=R.drawable.ic_favorite;
                nameItem.setTitle(a.getName());
                nameItem.setTitleCondensed(a.getShortName());



            }
            addFavoriteItem.setIcon(id);

        }
    });
}
```

and the xml where the items are defined:

```
      <item
    android:id="@+id/album_name"

    android:title="@string/album_name"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_save_all"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_save"
    android:title="@string/action_save_all"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_fav"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_favorite"
    android:title="@string/action_fav"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more layout for item 'album_name' :

```
<item
android:id="@+id/album_name"

android:title="@string/album_name"
yourapp:showAsAction="always"
yourapp:actionLayout="@layout/action_text"/>
```

then layout 'action_text' could be:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_name" 
    android:layout_width="text_width" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"       
    ... ...
            />
```

Hope this help.

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer :) I can't say, if this work with the v7 actionbar, since I decided to use ActionBarSherlock before you answered, sorry for that :/ I only can say that in ActionBarSherlock its not working. I can access the textview and change the text but there is still no marquee :(

Comment: It should work, my application just compatible backward to V7 and it scrolling nicely

Comment: so, i switched back to the v7 lib, and you're right, it works